# What is the motivation and intuition behind the Adjoint and Dual Operator?

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Those concepts were introduced, i.e.

**Adjoint Operator**

It's an operator $T^{*} \: : \: H_2 \rightarrow H_1$ such that $\forall _{x\in H_1,\:y\in H_2} \: \langle Tx, y \rangle_2 = \langle x, T^{*} y \rangle_1$

**Dual Operator**

We call $T'$ a dual operator, if: $$T' : \: Y^{*} \ni \Psi \: \rightarrow \: T' \Psi \in  X^{*}$$ where $X^{*} = \mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{C})$,  $Y^{*} = \mathcal{B}(Y,\mathbb{C})$

So the definitions are straight forward, but why are we introducing them in the first place? What's their "practical" use in Mathematics? And what's the intuition behind them?

Also, why is it important/interesting for them to be compact?

Comment: In finite dimensions, the adjoint is understandable as associated with the transpose of the matrix of the direct operator.

Comment: What is a direct operator?

Comment: I should have said "the initial operator"

Comment: Ok, now I understand. So what about the Dual Operator (defined like here)? How can this be interpreted on an easy example?